# Difference between FileVault encryption before/after OS X installation

Tags: macos, encryption

If I activate the FileVault HDD/SSD encryption feature on OS X after I installed OS X I'm *forced* to use a 'Recovery-Key' (predetermined breaking point for NSA etc?). When formatting the entire HDD/SSD before installing OS X with the Journaled/Encrypted option there is no 'Recovery-Key' set.

Or is it and OS X doesn't tell you? Is there any option to encrypt the whole drive with FileVault after installation without the need for a 'Recovery-Key' which makes the whole encryption nearly useless (especially if you save your 'Recovery-Key' in your iCloud)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the recovery key with:

```
sudo fdesetup removerecovery -personal
```

... but that's not going to increase your real security level at all. Apple claims the system isn't backdoored. If you believe them, you're safe anyway. If you don't believe them, there are far better ways to backdoor a system like this than the recovery key, so removing the recovery key (or preventing it from being generated in the first place) is unlikely to affect any actual backdoor.

BTW, Rich Trouton has a [good reference on managing FileVault from the command line on Mavericks](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/managing-mavericks-filevault-2-with-fdesetup/).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I think it's hard to believe any company this times..

When I disable the key, can the volume still be decrypted with it? (with a live cd / wrapped into a external hdd module on a other machine)